# Extract private key from pfx file or certificate store WITHOUT using OpenSSL on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, certificate-store

As the title suggests I would like to export my private key without using OpenSSL or any other third party tool. If I need a `.cer` file or `.pfx` file I can easily export these via MMC or PowerShell `pkiclient` but I can't find a way to get the private key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-certificate?view=win10-ps

Using an online tool like https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html is not OK.

PSVersion:

```
PS C:\Users\oscar> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.228
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.228
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I can get the public key like this:

```
(Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\localhost.pfx).GetPublicKey()
```

And export the entire certificate like this:

```
(Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\localhost.pfx).GetRawCertData()
```

Result from

```
PS C:\Users\oscar> $mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyPassword" -Force -AsPlainText
PS C:\Users\oscar> $mypfx = Get-PfxData -FilePath C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\localhost.pfx -Password $mypwd
PS C:\Users\oscar> $mypfx

OtherCertificates EndEntityCertificates
----------------- ---------------------
{}                {[Subject]...


PS C:\Users\oscar> $mypfx.EndEntityCertificates

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
8ED4971564E35099D6DB490C3756E2AD43AAAAAA  CN=localhost
```

Tested the command from @Brad but I got the error below.

> Private key is NOT plain text exportable

```
certutil -exportPFX -p "myPassword" -privatekey -user my <Certificate Serial Number> C:\localhost.pfx
```

[image]

Similar to Certificate Export Wizard in MMC certificates, only export to `.pfx` available if the key is included.

[image]

Comment: You certainly need a `.pfx` file as `.cer` files don't store private keys. What's your `$PSVersionTable` ? Can you use `Get-PfxData -FilePath 'mycertificate.pfx' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText -String 'MyClearTextPassword')` ?

Comment: @PetruZaharia Yes I'm aware, wrote that as an example of what you can export. :) Updated the question with PSVersion and what I have tried. I can but I have not found a way to export the private key.

Comment: Regarding `certutil`, I had the same problem.  I could export `.pfx` file with private key using Powershell: `Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\CurrentUser\Root\xyz -Force -FilePath keystore.pfx -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString password -AsPlainText -Force)`  The hard part: You need to find the cert thumbprint using something like: `ls cert:\CurrentUser\Root`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it with the help of [PSPKI Powershell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSPKI/3.7.2) from PS Gallery. While I understand that you look for a solution that preferably uses some built in functionality in Windows, installing a module from PS Gallery might be acceptable. At least it was in my case.

First install the PSPKI module (I assume hat the PSGallery repository has already been set up):

```
Install-Module -Name PSPKI
```

The PSPKI module provides a Cmdlet `Convert-PfxToPem` which converts a pfx-file to a pem-file which contains the certificate and pirvate key as base64-encoded text:

```
Convert-PfxToPem -InputFile C:\path\to\pfx\file.pfx -Outputfile C:\path\to\pem\file.pem
```

Now, all we need to do is splitting the pem-file with some regex magic. For example, like this:

```
(Get-Content C:\path\to\pem\file.pem -Raw) -match "(?ms)(\s*((?<privatekey>-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----.*?-
----END PRIVATE KEY-----)|(?<certificate>-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*?-----END CERTIFICATE-----))\s*){2}"

$Matches["privatekey"] | Set-Content "C:\path\to\key\file.pem"
$Matches["certificate"] | Set-Content "C:\path\to\certificate\file.pem"
```

Comment: Good answer but I would prefer to not use any third party library as you say. However since this is the best answer so far I will mark it as accepted until there is a better alternative. :)

Comment: I added a PowerShell script that incorporates the .NET approach to exporting the private key to a Pkcs8 PEM file.  I want to also point out that the PSPKI Convert-PfxToPem is very low level; using PInvoke to call Win32 methods.  Since .NET added support for CNG (Crypto Next Gen), we have all the capability we need via the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Comment: You can do this **without** the **third party** library: `$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $pfxFilePath; Export-Certificate -FilePath $derFilePath -Cert $cert; certutil -encode $derFilePath $pemFilePath | Out-Null` Now that you have pem file follow the rest of the posted answer. (I wish we could format code better in comments...)

Comment: @S.Melted This won't include the private key.

Answer (score 6):

I found [Panos.G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67852893/11942268) quite promising, but did not get it to work. All three described methods are not available on my certificate object. After more digging, I came up with the following solution:

*Note: It works, if you read the certificate from the certificate store. It does not work, if you read in a `.pfx` file with `Get-PfxCertificate`, for example. If you just have it as a file, you can install it in your certificate store to be able to read it from there as follows.*

```
# Read the certificate from the certificate store
# In this example, I use the certificate thumbprint to identify the certificate.
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -Recurse | ? {$_.Thumbprint -eq '<THUMBPRINT_OF_CERTIFICATE>'}

# Read the private key into an RSA CNG object:
$RSACng = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cert)

# Get the bytes of the private key
$KeyBytes = $RSACng.Key.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat]::Pkcs8PrivateBlob)

# Encode the bytes (Base64)
$KeyBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($KeyBytes, [System.Base64FormattingOptions]::InsertLineBreaks)

# Put it all together
$KeyPem = @"
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
$KeyBase64
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
"@
```

Docs:

- [`GetRSAPrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey?view=net-6.0)
- [`RSACng`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacng?view=net-6.0)
- [`Export()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey.export?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-cngkey-export(system-security-cryptography-cngkeyblobformat))
- [`Pkcs8PrivateBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkeyblobformat.pkcs8privateblob?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-cngkeyblobformat-pkcs8privateblob)
- [`ToBase64String()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-6.0#system-convert-tobase64string(system-byte()-system-base64formattingoptions))
- [`InsertLineBreaks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.base64formattingoptions?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Works great. Run from an elevated prompt

Comment: Win10 22H2 with PSVersion 5.1.19041.3570 fails as below. Elevated, and I imported directly from `Cert:\CurrentUser\My\<thumbprint>`  (note: I tried but I can't fix this terrible formatting) 
```Exception calling "Export" with "1" argument(s): "The requested operation is not supported.
"
At line:1 char:1
+ $KeyBytes = $RSACng.Key.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException```

Comment: @Nate I can reproduce the error. Looks like MS changed something... It does not even work anymore for certificates where the key *is* actually exportable.

Comment: Maybe plaintext exports are no longer supported and workarounds like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54525572/11942268) may work.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [existing answer by stackprotector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73023458/3293206) I'd like to add a fragment that works when reading directly from a .pfx file.

When reading from a file, you must use a method from .net core that allows specifying the X509StorageFlag Exportable instead of using PowerShells Get-PfxCertificate

```
# Password is a plain string, not a securestring
$cert=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2( 
      $filename, 
      $password, 
      [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)

# now continue as with the other solutions
# Read the private key into an RSA CNG object:
$RSACng = [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cert)

# Get the bytes of the private key
$KeyBytes = $RSACng.Key.Export([Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat]::Pkcs8PrivateBlob)

# Encode the bytes (Base64)
$KeyBase64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String($KeyBytes, [Base64FormattingOptions]::InsertLineBreaks)

# Put it all together
$KeyPem = @"
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
$KeyBase64
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what PowerShellGuy mentioned.

Will that work for you?

```
# first get your cert, either via pure .NET, or through the PSDrive (Cert:\)

# this is just an example

# get cert from PSDrive
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | where Subject -eq 'CN=MySubject'

# get cert from .NET
$My     = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My
$Store  = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new($My,'localmachine')
$Store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::MaxAllowed)

$cert   = $Store.Certificates | where Subject -eq 'CN=MySubject'

# get private key
# PKCS8, way #1
$BytesPkcs8 = $cert.PrivateKey.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($BytesPkcs8)

# PKCS8, way #2
$Pkcs = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat]::Pkcs8PrivateBlob
$BytesPkcs8 = $cert.PrivateKey.Key.Export($Pkcs)
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($BytesPkcs8)

# RSA
$BytesRsa = $cert.PrivateKey.ExportRSAPrivateKey()
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($BytesRsa)
```

So is that Base64 string what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Have you tried opening the cert store, and getting the private key that way? Pretty sure this will only work with RSA/DSA certs though.

```
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My,"localmachine")
$store.Open("MaxAllowed")
$cert = $store.Certificates | ?{$_.subject -match "^CN=asdasd"}
$cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString($false)
$store.Close()
```

Comment: I did get a value from this but it has to be modified. Your code results in:`<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>base64 value</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>`. However with `$cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(1)` and then converting that with RSA Key Converter - XML to PEM I do get the private key in base64. I have not found a way to do this with a built in Windows util though.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the cert to export with the script, identified by thumbprint The first line is for finding the thumbprint its the only line you need to edit replace yourthumbprintID with the certs thumbprint

```bash
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\
$cert = get-item "cert:\localmachine\my\YourcertsthumbprintID"
```

Public key to **Base64**

```bash
$CertBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.RawData, [System.Base64FormattingOptions]::InsertLineBreaks)
```

Private key to Base64

```bash
$RSACng = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cert)
$KeyBytes = $RSACng.Key.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat]::Pkcs8PrivateBlob)
$KeyBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($KeyBytes, [System.Base64FormattingOptions]::InsertLineBreaks)
```

Put it all together

```bash
$Pem = @"
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
$KeyBase64
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
$CertBase64
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"@
```

Output to file

```bash
$Pem | Out-File -FilePath cert.pem -Encoding Ascii
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly certutil should do it for you.

`certutil -exportPFX -p "ThePasswordToKeyonPFXFile" my [serialNumberOfCert] [fileNameOfPFx]`

Comment: Looked good but even though the helper said `Export certificate and private key` I got the message `Private key is NOT plain text exportable`. I could only export to `.pfx`. See updated question for print screen.