# X509Certificate2.Import with NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2, cng

I have a PFX certificate with CNG key inside (KSP provider information is specified in the PFX). I can't find a way to import the certificate in .NET in the way that would allow private key export in plain text (MS-CAPI format).

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes,password,X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

then I use this handle to acquire private key context by calling [CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecertificateprivatekey) function with enabled flag to allow CNG keys. The call succeeds.

When I call [NCryptExportKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptexportkey), the call fails with 0x8009000b error:

> Key not valid for use in specified state.

To debug this, I called [NCryptGetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptgetproperty) function to get export policy and indeed, `NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG` flag is enabled, but `NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG` is not. Tried to call the [NCryptSetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptsetproperty) function to enable this flag in Export Policy property, but the call fails with the same 0x8009000b error.

The question: how do I import pfx file in .NET from file without persisting the key and enabled `NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG` flag for CNG keys?

p.s. for some reasons I'm limited to .NET 4.0/4.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best flow I've found:

- Open the PFX Exportable (sets the exportable bit, but not the plaintext exportable bit)
- Export encrypted PKCS#8
- Import encrypted PKCS#8 with overwrite, no finalize
- Change the export policy
- Finalize (to commit the overwrite)
- Now if you ask the cert for its key it's plaintext exportable.

In net45 this takes a lot of code (thankfully [Export private key (PKCS#8) of CNG RSA certificate with oldschool .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55236230/6535399) did a lot of the work for me).  netcoreapp30 would do better, except that the import+alter+finalize would still need to be manual P/Invokes.

Tested with ECDsa, since that was the easiest way to force the CNG->CAPI bridge to not be utilized:

```
internal static partial class Program
{
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = ImportExportable(ECDsaP256_DigitalSignature_Pfx_Windows, "Test", machineScope: false);

        try
        {
            bool gotKey = NativeMethods.Crypt32.CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(
                cert.Handle,
                NativeMethods.Crypt32.AcquireCertificateKeyOptions.CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ONLY_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                out SafeNCryptKeyHandle keyHandle,
                out int keySpec,
                out bool callerFree);

            using (CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Open(keyHandle, 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cngKey.ExportPolicy);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        cngKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob)));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cert.Reset();
        }
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 ImportExportable(byte[] pfxBytes, string password, bool machineScope)
    {
        X509KeyStorageFlags flags = X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable;

        if (machineScope)
        {
            flags |= X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet;
        }
        else
        {
            flags |= X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet;
        }

        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes, password, flags);

        try
        {
            bool gotKey = NativeMethods.Crypt32.CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(
                cert.Handle,
                NativeMethods.Crypt32.AcquireCertificateKeyOptions.CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ONLY_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                out SafeNCryptKeyHandle keyHandle,
                out int keySpec,
                out bool callerFree);

            if (!gotKey)
            {
                keyHandle.Dispose();
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No private key");
            }

            if (!callerFree)
            {
                keyHandle.SetHandleAsInvalid();
                keyHandle.Dispose();
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Key is not persisted");
            }

            using (keyHandle)
            {
                // -1 == CNG, otherwise CAPI
                if (keySpec == -1)
                {
                    using (CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Open(keyHandle, CngKeyHandleOpenOptions.None))
                    {
                        // If the CNG->CAPI bridge opened the key then AllowPlaintextExport is already set.
                        if ((cngKey.ExportPolicy & CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport) == 0)
                        {
                            FixExportability(cngKey, machineScope);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            cert.Reset();
            throw;
        }

        return cert;
    }

    internal static void FixExportability(CngKey cngKey, bool machineScope)
    {
        string password = nameof(NativeMethods.Crypt32.AcquireCertificateKeyOptions);
        byte[] encryptedPkcs8 = ExportEncryptedPkcs8(cngKey, password, 1);
        string keyName = cngKey.KeyName;

        using (SafeNCryptProviderHandle provHandle = cngKey.ProviderHandle)
        {
            ImportEncryptedPkcs8Overwrite(
                encryptedPkcs8,
                keyName,
                provHandle,
                machineScope,
                password);
        }
    }

    internal const string NCRYPT_PKCS8_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB = "PKCS8_PRIVATEKEY";
    private static readonly byte[] s_pkcs12TripleDesOidBytes =
        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3\0");

    private static unsafe byte[] ExportEncryptedPkcs8(
        CngKey cngKey,
        string password,
        int kdfCount)
    {
        var pbeParams = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.PbeParams();
        NativeMethods.NCrypt.PbeParams* pbeParamsPtr = &pbeParams;

        byte[] salt = new byte[NativeMethods.NCrypt.PbeParams.RgbSaltSize];

        using (RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(salt);
        }

        pbeParams.Params.cbSalt = salt.Length;
        Marshal.Copy(salt, 0, (IntPtr)pbeParams.rgbSalt, salt.Length);
        pbeParams.Params.iIterations = kdfCount;

        fixed (char* stringPtr = password)
        fixed (byte* oidPtr = s_pkcs12TripleDesOidBytes)
        {
            NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer* buffers =
                stackalloc NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer[3];

            buffers[0] = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer
            {
                BufferType = NativeMethods.NCrypt.BufferType.PkcsSecret,
                cbBuffer = checked(2 * (password.Length + 1)),
                pvBuffer = (IntPtr)stringPtr,
            };

            if (buffers[0].pvBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                buffers[0].cbBuffer = 0;
            }

            buffers[1] = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer
            {
                BufferType = NativeMethods.NCrypt.BufferType.PkcsAlgOid,
                cbBuffer = s_pkcs12TripleDesOidBytes.Length,
                pvBuffer = (IntPtr)oidPtr,
            };

            buffers[2] = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer
            {
                BufferType = NativeMethods.NCrypt.BufferType.PkcsAlgParam,
                cbBuffer = sizeof(NativeMethods.NCrypt.PbeParams),
                pvBuffer = (IntPtr)pbeParamsPtr,
            };

            var desc = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBufferDesc
            {
                cBuffers = 3,
                pBuffers = (IntPtr)buffers,
                ulVersion = 0,
            };

            using (var keyHandle = cngKey.Handle)
            {
                int result = NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptExportKey(
                    keyHandle,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    NCRYPT_PKCS8_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB,
                    ref desc,
                    null,
                    0,
                    out int bytesNeeded,
                    0);

                if (result != 0)
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(result);
                }

                byte[] exported = new byte[bytesNeeded];

                result = NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptExportKey(
                    keyHandle,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    NCRYPT_PKCS8_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB,
                    ref desc,
                    exported,
                    exported.Length,
                    out bytesNeeded,
                    0);

                if (result != 0)
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(result);
                }

                if (bytesNeeded != exported.Length)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref exported, bytesNeeded);
                }

                return exported;
            }
        }
    }

    private static unsafe void ImportEncryptedPkcs8Overwrite(
        byte[] encryptedPkcs8,
        string keyName,
        SafeNCryptProviderHandle provHandle,
        bool machineScope,
        string password)
    {
        SafeNCryptKeyHandle keyHandle;

        fixed (char* passwordPtr = password)
        fixed (char* keyNamePtr = keyName)
        fixed (byte* blobPtr = encryptedPkcs8)
        {
            NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer* buffers = stackalloc NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer[2];

            buffers[0] = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer
            {
                BufferType = NativeMethods.NCrypt.BufferType.PkcsSecret,
                cbBuffer = checked(2 * (password.Length + 1)),
                pvBuffer = new IntPtr(passwordPtr),
            };

            if (buffers[0].pvBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                buffers[0].cbBuffer = 0;
            }

            buffers[1] = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBuffer
            {
                BufferType = NativeMethods.NCrypt.BufferType.PkcsName,
                cbBuffer = checked(2 * (keyName.Length + 1)),
                pvBuffer = new IntPtr(keyNamePtr),
            };

            NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBufferDesc desc = new NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptBufferDesc
            {
                cBuffers = 2,
                pBuffers = (IntPtr)buffers,
                ulVersion = 0,
            };

            NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptImportFlags flags =
                NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptImportFlags.NCRYPT_OVERWRITE_KEY_FLAG |
                NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptImportFlags.NCRYPT_DO_NOT_FINALIZE_FLAG;

            if (machineScope)
            {
                flags |= NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptImportFlags.NCRYPT_MACHINE_KEY_FLAG;
            }

            int errorCode = NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptImportKey(
                provHandle,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                NCRYPT_PKCS8_PRIVATE_KEY_BLOB,
                ref desc,
                out keyHandle,
                new IntPtr(blobPtr),
                encryptedPkcs8.Length,
                flags);

            if (errorCode != 0)
            {
                keyHandle.Dispose();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }

            using (keyHandle)
            using (CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Open(keyHandle, CngKeyHandleOpenOptions.None))
            {
                const CngExportPolicies desiredPolicies =
                    CngExportPolicies.AllowExport | CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport;

                cngKey.SetProperty(
                    new CngProperty(
                        "Export Policy",
                        BitConverter.GetBytes((int)desiredPolicies),
                        CngPropertyOptions.Persist));

                int error = NativeMethods.NCrypt.NCryptFinalizeKey(keyHandle, 0);

                if (error != 0)
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    internal static class Crypt32
    {
        internal enum AcquireCertificateKeyOptions
        {
            None = 0x00000000,
            CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ONLY_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG = 0x00040000,
        }

        [DllImport("crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(
            IntPtr pCert,
            AcquireCertificateKeyOptions dwFlags,
            IntPtr pvReserved,
            out SafeNCryptKeyHandle phCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
            out int dwKeySpec,
            out bool pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey);
    }

    internal static class NCrypt
    {
        [DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern int NCryptExportKey(
            SafeNCryptKeyHandle hKey,
            IntPtr hExportKey,
            string pszBlobType,
            ref NCryptBufferDesc pParameterList,
            byte[] pbOutput,
            int cbOutput,
            [Out] out int pcbResult,
            int dwFlags);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal unsafe struct PbeParams
        {
            internal const int RgbSaltSize = 8;

            internal CryptPkcs12PbeParams Params;
            internal fixed byte rgbSalt[RgbSaltSize];
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct CryptPkcs12PbeParams
        {
            internal int iIterations;
            internal int cbSalt;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct NCryptBufferDesc
        {
            public int ulVersion;
            public int cBuffers;
            public IntPtr pBuffers;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct NCryptBuffer
        {
            public int cbBuffer;
            public BufferType BufferType;
            public IntPtr pvBuffer;
        }

        internal enum BufferType
        {
            PkcsAlgOid = 41,
            PkcsAlgParam = 42,
            PkcsName = 45,
            PkcsSecret = 46,
        }

        [DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern int NCryptOpenStorageProvider(
            out SafeNCryptProviderHandle phProvider,
            string pszProviderName,
            int dwFlags);

        internal enum NCryptImportFlags
        {
            None = 0,
            NCRYPT_MACHINE_KEY_FLAG = 0x00000020,
            NCRYPT_OVERWRITE_KEY_FLAG = 0x00000080,
            NCRYPT_DO_NOT_FINALIZE_FLAG = 0x00000400,
        }

        [DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern int NCryptImportKey(
            SafeNCryptProviderHandle hProvider,
            IntPtr hImportKey,
            string pszBlobType,
            ref NCryptBufferDesc pParameterList,
            out SafeNCryptKeyHandle phKey,
            IntPtr pbData,
            int cbData,
            NCryptImportFlags dwFlags);

        [DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern int NCryptFinalizeKey(SafeNCryptKeyHandle hKey, int dwFlags);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look into this. Too much code. Also, I tried this approach: load PFX using `PFXImportCertStore` function. It succeeds, I can create an instance of `X509Store` from acquired handle, can view certificates in store. But `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` doesn't seem to be able to resolve the handle of the certificate from the in-memory store created by `PFXImportCertStore`.

Comment: @Crypt32 it might also work using the hExportKey parameter, but I’ve never looked into that. Same flow, but might take less code.

Comment: A follow up: I was able to convert the code to get rid of all `unsafe` and `fixed` statements and pointers. And I found that I don't need to call `CryptAcquirePrivateKeyContext` again (and this doesn't work). Instead, I can use `keyHandle` in the `ImportEncryptedPkcs8Overwrite` method right after it is finalized and changes are committed. Anyway, it does work for at least ECDSA keys.

Comment: @Crypt32 Do you remember how you converted this to not use the unsafe/fixed statements and pointers?