# How to get private key as Byte[] of a password protected pfx fetched from azure key vault

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, private-key, x509certificate2

I am fetching my certificate from Azure Key Vault using GetSecretAsync() method and then I am expecting to get the byte[] of the private key and the certificate eventually.

I have my application in .netcore3.1
This is how my code looks like :

```
var certWithPrivateKey = Client.GetSecretAsync(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AKVEndpoint"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CertName"]).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certWithPrivateKey.Value);

X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes);
var privateKey = x509Certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey() as RSA;
```

I get a valid privateKey of type RSACng, but any operation (tried ExportRSAPrivateKey()) on that throws an error of "'privateKey.ExportRSAPrivateKey()' threw an exception of type 'Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException'" and "The requested operation is not supported."

I am not sure how to proceed next here to get the byte[] of the private key and certificate.

Comment: Why don't you use keys instead of secrets?

Comment: Why do you need the private key to be exported? What's the end goal?

Comment: I want to eventually install that certificate in my kubernetes cluster as a tls secret, so I am expecting to get the byte[] of private key and certificate to eventually make a .cer and .key file and use them to create the secret.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you do actually seem to need to export: Your current code doesn't load the private key as exportable, so it can't be exported.  The fix is to assert exportability:

```
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate =
    new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

If that's not enough, then you're encountering the difference between CAPI exportability and CNG exportability (Windows older, and newer, crypto libraries).  If the private key from a PFX/PKCS#12 gets loaded into CNG it's only "encrypted exportable", but ExportParameters is plaintext-export.

There's a workaround, though... export it encrypted, then import that somewhere else with a more flexible export policy, then export again.

This snippet uses the .NET Core 3.0+ [ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.exportpkcs8privatekey?view=netcore-3.1) method, since that's the format you want your data in, and new .NET 5 [PemEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pemencoding?view=net-5.0) class to simplify turning the DER encoded output into PEM+DER output.  If your exporter is on .NET Framework, this is a [more complex problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57330499/6535399). For .NET Standard 2.0 there's not really a clean solution (reflect call the methods for .NET Core/.NET 5, otherwise use the Windows-specific version for .NET Framework?).

```
byte[] pkcs8PrivateKey;

using (RSA privateKey = x509Certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    pkcs8PrivateKey = ExportPrivateKey(privateKey);
}

File.WriteAllText(
    "tls.cer",
    new string(PemEncoding.Write("CERTIFICATE", x509Certificate.RawData));

File.WriteAllText(
    "tls.key",
    new string(PemEncoding.Write("PRIVATE KEY", pkcs8PrivateKey));

...

private static byte[] ExportPrivateKey(RSA privateKey)
{
    try
    {
        // If it's plaintext exportable, just do the easy thing.
        return privateKey.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
    }
    catch (CryptographicException)
    {
    }

    using (RSA exportRewriter = RSA.Create())
    {
        // Only one KDF iteration is being used here since it's immediately being
        // imported again.  Use more if you're actually exporting encrypted keys.
        exportRewriter.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(
            "password",
            privateKey.ExportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(
                "password",
                new PbeParameters(
                    PbeEncryptionAlgorithm.Aes128Cbc,
                    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                    1)),
            out _);

        return exportRewriter.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @bartonjs for the detailed answer. The first snippet to assert ex-portability solved the problem for me, I was able to directly get the byte[] from ExportPkcs8PrivateKey() post that. I skipped the file creation part for now as I am now using kubernetes client for C# for creating the tls secret, which accepts byte[] directly.