# RSA? GetPrivateKey extension method return null

Tags: c#, x509certificate, private-key, x509certificate2

I have this extension method GetRSAPrivateKey()...

```
public static class X509CertificateExtensions
{
    public static RSA? GetRSAPrivateKey(this X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(certificate));
        }

        RSA? rsaPrivateKey = null;

        // Check if the private key exists
        if (certificate.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            // Try to get the RSA private key from the certificate
            try
            {
                rsaPrivateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions, such as an invalid or non-exportable private key
                rsaPrivateKey = null;
            }
        }

        return rsaPrivateKey;
    }
}
```

It returns null eventhough the cerificate.HasPrivateKey==true,
I can see that there is a private key in the certificate when viewed in a tool like kestore explorer.

Comment: You should add a language tag. I'm guessing `[c#]`?

Comment: You don't show where/how you created the X509Certificate2, but depending how you did it [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54483371/238704) may be a duplicate of yours. This again illustrates the value of a [mre].

Comment: What is `certificate.PublicKey.Oid.Value`?

Comment: Console.WriteLine($"certificate.PublicKey.Oid.Value = {certificate.PublicKey.Oid.Value}");
certificate.PublicKey.Oid.Value = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1

Comment: That OID, with `HasPrivateKey == true` should always return non-null, or throw (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/RSACertificateExtensions.cs,82ffbf83218c9fb0).  If it's throwing, and your code there is ignoring the exception, then debugging clearly starts at "what is the exception?"

Comment: It appears it does not work when implemented as an extension method, but works fine as internal static method. Thanks